# Always use specified option when rebasing

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-config

I recently discovered the `--committer-date-is-author-date` option for `git rebase`.  I'd like to make this the global default whenever I rebase.  Is there a way to modify `.gitconfig` so that this option is always used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An option would be to create an alias of the command that includes the option.

https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Git-Aliases

`git config global --alias.re 'rebase --committer-date-is-author-date'`